# How to make video call in flutter with agora?

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, agora.io, videochat

I am using official flutter agora example for making video call , but the local camera only opens , and the remote user is never called.

packages :
"agora_rtc_engine: ^4.2.0"
"permission_handler: ^8.3.0"

This is the official example
https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine/example

and this I am following this tutorial also
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVqs1EIpVxs

**and this is my code**

```
    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
    import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_local_view.dart' as RtcLocalView;
    import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_remote_view.dart' as RtcRemoteView;
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
    
    const appId = "843b5a8f8c3a4e0fbe2c804654f4ce36";
    const token = "006843b5a8f8c3a4e0fbe2c804654f4ce36IAA4Le0bHwiNWScQ3+1c4sM+UXErd0xfOdjuoZRe1Dz8B9vEKrAAAAAAEADVz7HmNwPgYQEAAQAWA+Bh";
    
    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      int? _remoteUid;
      bool _localUserJoined = false;
      late RtcEngine _engine;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initAgora();
      }
    
      Future<void> initAgora() async {
        // retrieve permissions
        await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
    
        //create the engine
        _engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
        await _engine.enableVideo();
        _engine.setEventHandler(
          RtcEngineEventHandler(
            joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
              print("local user $uid joined");
              setState(() {
                _localUserJoined = true;
              });
            },
            userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
              print("remote user $uid joined");
              setState(() {
                _remoteUid = uid;
              });
            },
            userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
              print("remote user $uid left channel");
              setState(() {
                _remoteUid = null;
              });
            },
            
          ),
        );
    
        await _engine.joinChannel(token, "test_video_call", null, 0);
      }
    
      // Create UI with local view and remote view
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: _remoteVideo(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 150,
                  child: Center(
                    child: _localUserJoined
                        ? RtcLocalView.SurfaceView()
                        : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      // Display remote user's video
      Widget _remoteVideo() {
        if (_remoteUid != null) {
          return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: _remoteUid!);
        } else {
          return Text(
            'Please wait for remote user to join',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using same channel name for both users?

Comment: Yes, I am running the same project for two deferent mobile devices @Diwyansh

Comment: How old your token is?

Comment: @Diwyansh Token expires on January 13, 2022 1:25 PM UTC

Comment: I hope you are enabled the token verification and also using the token with relevant appId?

Comment: I am using test mode , so is there a verification of token in this mode ? @Diwyansh

Comment: Yes if token is enabled then it will ask for verfication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also gone through the sample code available in the plugin `example` but there are few thing that you need to `ensure`.

1. `UID` should be different for each user (put 0 if testing)
2. `token` should be from same `AppId` used in create method. (if token is enabled)
3. `Token` expires in `24 hours` so make sure that token is working.
4. `Channel name` should be `unique`

Comment: so how i will get the tokken for the production